# Different endpoints to get a resource in a API REST

Tags: rest

I have a REST API with a **GET** endpoint to retrieve a product based on the id. Now I need to retrieve a product based on another attribute and I don't know if I have to use the same endpoint and handle the multiple cases there or write different endpoints, one for each case.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mauricio, just wondering if you were able to solve your problem. If my answer was helpful an upvote and/or marking it as accepted would be appreciated. =)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have

`GET /product/{id}`

And you want to be able to lookup products by some other attribute. If the attribute uniquely identifies a product you could do:

`GET /product?someOtherAttribute=foo`

return

```
302 FOUND
Location: /product/5
```

If you want to avoid the roundtrip you could return the contents of product directly, but as you pointed out that may require additional logic in your controller.

If the attribute does not uniquely identify a product, I'd recommend a paginated collection response:

`GET /products?someOtherAttribute=foo`

return

```
200 OK
{
   products: [{
       url: "/product/5"
   }, {
       url: "/product/6"
   }]
}
```